# Sending Non-latin query string in URL in JavaME

Tags: java, java-me

I want to make am HTTP GET request from my J2ME application using HttpConnection class.
The problem is that I cannot send russian text in the query string. 
Here is the example of how I'm sending the request

```
c = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://127.0.0.1:1418/zp.ashx?тест");
InputStream s = c.openInputStream();
```

The receiving asp.net script receives the query part of the url as %3f%3f%3f%3f

That is 4 identical codes. Definately that's not what I'm sending

So how can I send non-latin text in an http query in J2ME?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
Connector.open("http://127.0.0.1:1418/zp.ashx?тест");
```

is processed by a [java.nio.CharsetDecoder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) for the ASCII character set, and this decoder replaces all unknown characters with its [replacement](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#replacement%28%29).

To get the behavior you want, you have to encode the URL before sending it. For example, when your server expects the URLs to be UTF8-encoded:

```
String encodedParameter = URLEncoder.encode("тест", "UTF-8");
Connector.open("http://127.0.0.1:1418/zp.ashx?" + encodedParameter);
```

Note that if you have multiple parameters, you have to encode both the parameter names and the parameter values individually, before putting them together with "=" and concatenating them with "&". If you need to encode multiple parameters, this class may be helpful to you:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class UrlParamGenerator {
  private final String encoding;
  private final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  private String separator = "?";

  public UrlParamGenerator(String charset) {
    this.encoding = charset;
  }

  public void add(String key, String value) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    sb.append(separator);
    sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, encoding));
    sb.append("=");
    sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(value, encoding));
    separator = "&";
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    UrlParamGenerator gen = new UrlParamGenerator("UTF-8");
    gen.add("test", "\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442");
    gen.add("x", "0");
    System.out.println(gen.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to explicitly set a character set in the HTTP header that supports the cyrillic alphabet. You could either use UTF-8 or another charset, such as windows-1251 (although UTF-8 should be the preferred choice).

```
c.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");    
c = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://127.0.0.1:1418/zp.ashx?тест");
```

If you use an appropriate charset, the server should be able to properly handle the cyrillic request parameter - provided it too supports this charset.

Answer (score 1):

URL can contain only ASCII chars and a few punctuation chars. For other chars, you must %-encode them before adding them in the URL. Use `URLEncoder.encode("тест", enc)` where the `enc` parameter is the encoding scheme that the server *expects*.